# Robocopy - File names with an Ampersand

Tags: batch-file, robocopy

So I have a pretty basic batch script that looks at an incoming folder and based on file type moves files where I want them. Now folders that show up with "&" in them break it. How do you go about fixing this? I couldn't find an obvious answer online.

```
robocopy.exe "%location%" "%destination%" /E /tee /LOG+:C:\Users\etc\Log.txt
```

EDIT 2:

OK thanks to the comments bellow and a bunch of trail and error I figured that it was a quotation issue. Now after a bunch of trial and error found a combination of quotes and no quotes that worked, I have no idea why though. If some one is able to explain why this works and other combinations didn't I would appreciate it haha...batch is so weird.

`Input -> Test.bat "C:\etc\etc\"` - Path in quotes

`set location=%1` - No Quotes

`set type="%~2"` - Quotes

`set destination="C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\Destination"` - Quotes

`set logfile="C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\robolog.txt"` - Quotes

`robocopy.exe %location% "%destination%" /E /tee /LOG+:%logfile%` - Source with no quotes but destination in quotes???

Do quotes cancel each other out? I'm confused why adding quotes would make it not work, but only work in some cases?
Also having %~1 vs %1 vs "%1" vs "%~1" produced different results.

Comment: Do you mean source or target folders, or in the folders that are copied.  if the source/target are doubled quoted as you have shown, they should work fine with an &

Comment: The command that you've posted doesn't seem vulnerable to ampersands in file/folder names. The issue may occur prior to calling `robocopy`. Perhaps it's to do with how you are assigning the `location` and `destination` variables. Put double quotation marks around the assignment, `SET "var=value"`, like in @Dany Bee's answer, and you should be fine. (You'll still need the double quotes in the `robocopy` command line.)

Comment: Check if `%location%` or `%destination%` are not already quoted.

Comment: I updated the main post with more info

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I tested this:

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL
SET "location=this & that"
SET "destination=more & more"
robocopy.exe "%location%" "%destination%" /E /tee /LOG+:"%destination%\Log.txt"
```

And I got no error:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ROBOCOPY     ::     Robust File Copy for Windows     ::     Version XP010
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  Started : Wed Jul 31 09:59:55 2013

   Source : C:\TEST\this & that\
     Dest : C:\TEST\more & more\

    Files : *.*

  Options : *.* /TEE /S /E /COPY:DAT /R:1000000 /W:30 

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

---

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

                Total    Copied   Skipped  Mismatch    FAILED    Extras
     Dirs :         1         0         1         0         0         0
    Files :        81        81         0         0         0         1
    Bytes :    28.3 k    28.3 k         0         0         0         0
    Times :   0:00:00   0:00:00                       0:00:00   0:00:00

    Speed :              184585 Bytes/sec.
    Speed :              10.562 MegaBytes/min.

    Ended : Wed Jul 31 09:59:55 2013
```

Comment: Ok so I made up a similar test batch file and it does indeed work. The issues stem from my lack of understanding of how batch uses quotations i think

Comment: Finally a solution to copy my \Lounge & Chillout\ Folder. To write the " in front of the variable name is absolutely new to me. But it really works. @dany-bee: Could you explain this syntax?